# No icons, launcher, top panel or anything else while 'Try Ubuntu' 13.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, installation, multi-boot

I just got Ubuntu 13.04 to my USB and pressed 'Try Ubuntu' and that worked very well, so I decided to install. At the end of the install I got a fail message and it said something about the boot loader, and that made me unable to boot to Ubuntu.

I wanted to use the boot-repair tool, but the problem is now that, when I go to 'Try Ubuntu' I just get the background but no icons, top bar or anything like that? Only the background and my mouse. I can't open anything, but just chill with my mouse.

I tried (old Windows user) to press ctrl+alt+delete and that logged me out. It said I could log in again, but I don't really know what username to use or which password that is useful. I've been trying to reboot several times, but I just get the same result.

Is it possible for me to use the boot-repair tool in another way than with the 'Try Ubuntu' or can I fix the icon, launcher, top bar in a way (without using the Termal. Since I can't open it).

Answer (score 2):

From the sounds of it there was a problem during the installation. If I was you, I would get the CD or USB and do a complete clean reinstall.

Comment: Yep, reinstall. Sounds like the best solution as this is a clean install. I see the question is asked two hours before. That would have been enough to do this several times.

Comment: I tried too, but with the same result. I'm not sure if I just don't know how to use the ubuntu after install (without USB and Disk). How can I go to ubuntu?

Comment: Are you just doing a clean install on an empty system?

Comment: I think what you should do is re-download the iso file from the Ubuntu website, then wipe the CD/ get a new CD and burn the iso to it. Put I'm in your PC and start it up, run the installer as normal. Does is work?